# How to open an external file from a link

Tags: hyperref

Please can you tell me the command to be used for the following:

aa.pdf is an external pdf in my computer. I want then when I click on aa.pdf from the pdf generated using this latex file it should open. But it is not opening. Please suggest

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}


\section{\textcolor{red}{Acknowledgement}}
Practice School 1 at Guru Nanak Dev Thermal Power plant was a very interesting and innovating experience. This report is a product of valuable advice and s
\newpage

\section{\textcolor{red}{Abstract}}

Thermal power plants are a  major source of generation of electricity for any developing country. Around 60\% of electricity generation in our country is met by 

\newpage

\section{\textcolor{red}{GNDTP - A coal based Plant}}
\section{\textcolor{red}{Introduction}}

Electricity is not just a convenience; its a necessity. It helps us live comfortably in our homes year-round, regardless of the weather. A safe, reliable and a

\section{ Report}
hyperref[labelname]{aa.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this question have anything related to LaTeX?

Comment: Try `\href` from the `hyperref` package, but you really need to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: I added it. Please suggest now.

Comment: Please use the `code` environment to present your code, and remove all code not pertinent for your question. You should have a look at [related questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191725/external-file-pls-answer#h-related), too.

Comment: I did it. Please tell now

Comment: @shivam : you should transform that comment into a (at least minimal) answer and accept it, so that you can close this question.

Comment: Or is it a duplicate? If so, tell us which question you found which gave you the answer and we can mark this one as a duplicate so other users can find the solution.